# Why did the bullet catch go wrong in The Prestige?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

In the scene where Borden was performing a bullet catch trick he gave the gun to an audience member. So, he was really expecting the audience member to shoot the bullet.

Then Angier gets the pistol and shoots Borden. Doesn't that mean a random audience member could also, possibly, really shoot Borden?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The audience member was supposed to be shooting a blank; and then Borden would have pretended to catch the bullet while producing a hidden bullet. Angier slipped something else in the barrel that struck Borden; you can briefly see him messing with the barrel right before the shot.

Cutter indirectly explains this in the film:

> Cutter: A bullet catch is suicide, all it takes is some smart-ass volunteer to put a button in the barrel...

This implies that a real bullet was not expected to be fired; because if it were, putting a button in the barrel wouldn’t add danger.

Comment: They even explain the bullet trick at some point. Right after putting it in Borden secretly grabs the bullet from the barrel with the stick that he stuffs the powder into with (or whatever it's called).

Comment: There's actually a "blink-and-you-miss-it" shot of Angier sliding his fingers along the opening of the gun right after he gets it (notably after Borden turns his back). That's when he puts something in the barrel. There's even a small sound effect of something clinking against metal.

Comment: I've seen bullet catch tricks. Without exception, they've all assumed the audience *don't know what a bullet is*.  The bullet is only the projectile - the cartridge case gets left behind. Every single one has produced a complete unfired cartridge as the "caught bullet".

Comment: Re the "object in the barrel", that's how Brandon Lee died. A blank cartridge has the normal amount of powder, but no bullet. If there's anything else stuck in the barrel, it becomes a projectile with the same force as a bullet.

Comment: You can see the action here: https://youtu.be/LTmPV3AhhnQ?t=1m11s
To be clear, Angiers does not replace the blank. He slips something into the barrel such that the blank will propel it.

Comment: @Graham you've not seen Penn & Teller then?

Comment: @Graham - you need to watch [Penn & Teller's bullet catch trick](https://youtu.be/DK0-ImFaSG4) where the participating audience members have firearms experience and they clearly differentiate between the bullet and the cartrididge case.

Comment: @OrangeDog and LaconicDroid Thanks for those links - nice to see that someone does do it properly!  To be fair to Penn and Teller, they're usually very good at that (which is why I like them, and why too many others are disappointing).

Comment: Not disagreeing with you (we know how the trick works), but I think your explanation is not convincing enough: _"This implies that a real bullet was not expected to be fired; because if it were, **putting a button in the barrel wouldn’t add danger**."_ → Well, to be fair... If a bullet _were_ already in the barrel and Borden _were_ able to catch it, adding a button (or any other kind of additional projectile) would mean there'd be **two** bullets now, of which Borden could catch only one. So putting a button certainly adds danger, no matter if a real bullet was expected or not.